# CakePHP :: Adding a default date into a DOB field with the form helper?

Tags: php, cakephp

This might be a very simple answer but all my research so far is not coming up with an answer!

I am using CakePHP 2.4 I have set up a Form using the CakePHP helper, with a dob field within the list,

```
 $DOBOps = array('label' => 'D.O.B','div' => false, 'type' => 'date',
           'dateFormat' => 'DMY','maxYear' => date('Y') - 100,
           'minYear' => date('Y'), 'default' => $UserDOB);

 $this->Form->input('dobraw', $DOBOps);
```

Now its called dobraw so it does not list in my `$this->data` as dob becuase I want to convert it 1st. So I take the day, month and year and use PHP to convert it to a simple timestamp, which I then set as the dob using `$this->request->data`.

This all works, my code converts it fine and saves the data into the database, but when I go back to the user profile / settings page I want it to update the form with the data saved into the database.

I have tried, adding a default tag to it but it does not work, I have also converted back to dd-mm-yyyy format, so `$UserDOB` holds a data not a timestamp.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it, I thought that because it was loading dd-mm-yyyy. I would have to set the data I am giving it to the same format - but I seems to work when I get it the pure timestamp.

If there is a better way of doing it please let me know.

Thanks.